# How to dynamically create and position a textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to dynamically create a text box then dynamically position the text box.  I have been able to dynamically create the text box with no problem but I have not been able to figure out how to position it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try to make your question titles meaningful. "Javascript question" is not going to be of much use to someone searching the archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var box = document.createElement('input'); // creates the element

box.style.position = 'absolute';  // position it
box.style.left = '100px';
box.style.top = '100px';  

document.body.appendChild(box); // add it as last child of body elemnt
```

If you want to add it somewhere else in the document hierarchy you have to find the parent using getElementById and use that elements appendChild function.

Answer (score 2):

Set the "top" and "left" positions? You may also need to set the "position" property to be "relative" or "absolute", depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Position where?

Are you trying to position at some specific point or inside some other element?
Try using position: absolute either in the CSS for your textbox class or use the style property on the object in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to positioning elements using javascript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myelementID');
el.style.left = 10 + "px";
el.style.top = 10 + "px";
```

Note the `' + "px"'` part of that.  You need to make sure the expression is a string with units before the assignment takes place or it won't work reliably.  You can also use the `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` properties instead of the style, but the "string with units" rule still applies.

Comment: You also need to set the 'position' property to 'absolute', otherwise the 'left'/'top' properties won't do anything.

Comment: I was figuring he'd already done that, but yes, that is necessary as well.